# Calling a Java set method from a tag or jsp

Tags: java, jstl, el

I am trying to call a set method from a tag file.  Here is my code:

```
<c:set var="countryCode" value="${proposalPerson.countryCode}"/>
<c:set value="${f:KualiForm.setCurrentPersonCountryCode(countryCode)}"/>
```

the second statement is the set statement that I am having problems with.  Just for note, this tag looping through a List of objects, and I need to set this value for proccessing server side lower on in the code.  Anyway, the error I have gotten is:

```
PWC6296: The function setCurrentPersonCountryCode 
must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified
```

I've found a few related posts on this site, but none seem to be working for me.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code I needed:

```
<c:set var="currentCountryCode" value="${KualiForm.document.developmentProposalList[0].proposalPersons[personIndex].countryCode}"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="KualiForm" property="currentPersonCountryCode" value="${currentCountryCode }"  />
```